# How to summarize data by month?

Tags: kql

I am trying to summarize my data monthly.
Using something like
`

```
bin_at(TimeGenerated, 30d,datetime(2022-01-01 00:00:00))
```

`
does give me data at an interval of 30 days, but it does not account for the irregularity in dates. Like it does not handle the fact that January has 31 does but feb has only 28.
I read the documentation but I found nothing I could use.

This is what I have tried and if you're aware of anything that might help me, please comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[startofmonth()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startofmonthfunction)

```
startofmonth(TimeGenerated)
```

Demo:

```
range i from 1 to 1000 step 1 
| extend TimeGenerated = ago(100d *rand())
| summarize count() by startofmonth = startofmonth(TimeGenerated)
```

| startofmonth | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01T00:00:00Z | 134 |
| 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z | 312 |
| 2022-10-01T00:00:00Z | 310 |
| 2022-11-01T00:00:00Z | 244 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WMMQ7CMAxFd6Te4Y8JU3oAZi7ABUzjlgy2K9eVCuLwhA3GJ733nHRhNMxughFhGEsp2ILXjsPpDT6CteLWhK%20s7BRccQEtlrpacXbSmnL%20utsuQt5ejMl2jZRxf/YXedgspvHo4S%20mv2v%20ADxz/9eNAAAA)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: See updated answer for a demo.